# What is the best way to store slow-changing attributes in a data warehouse?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

In classic relational data warehouse design slow-changing attributes (attributes that change infrequently) are stored in a table with a schema similar to this:

*EntityKey, StartDate, EndDate, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3...*

(This might be by contrast to fast-changing attributes, which could be stored as:
*EntityKey, Timestamp, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3...*)

What I don't like about this approach is that there is a lot of repeated information. If Attribute1 changes once a week and Attribute2 only once a year, you end up repeating Attribute2 every week redundantly. If you have a lot of attributes that can add up.

Of course, you could create one such table for each time interval (a table for weekly attributes, one for monthly, one for yearly, etc.) but in the real world various attributes will change at various points in time, not necessarily according to any pattern. Also for some entities the same attribute may change more frequently than for others.

I am curious if anyone has suggestions or ideas for different storage schemas for such attributes that change infrequently but with different frequencies (i.e. some change daily, others weekly, etc.). Perhaps there are (non-relational) database technologies I am not aware of that are more suited for this type of problem?

Answer (score 7):

> What I don't like about this approach is that there is a lot of repeated information.

That's the point of a warehouse.  Repeat the information to represent (a) historical facts as they occurred and (b) reduce the number of joins.

> If Attribute1 changes once a week and Attribute2 only once a year, you end up repeating Attribute2 every week redundantly. If you have a lot of attributes that can add up.

Wrong.  It doesn't add up very quickly at all.

You appear to be talking about dimensions in a star schema.  They're relatively small. The storage is irrelevant compared to the fact tables.  Don't normalize or optimize.  Consider this a "pre-joined", "high-speed", "denormalized", "reporting-only" table.  Be happy with non-normalized data: it's faster.

If you're talking about a Fact Table, then these changes have different time granularity and **never** should have been in the same fact table.

Comment: I did not want to qualify the data as dimension or fact because the situation (slow-changing attributes, aka Type 2 in Kimble literature) could occur both for fact and for dimension data. I agree that this type of schema is typically applied to dimension data and that dimension data grows relatively slowly (compared to fact data perhaps).

That being said, I am still curious if there are other ideas out there for storing slow changing attributes in a more efficient fashion, even if the redundant data is not that big. I do see your point about regarding these tables as "pre-joined."

Comment: No.  Slow-changing attributes cannot happen in a fact table.  That's got a well-defined approach: create a new fact row.  Not a change to an existing fact row.  "Slowly Changing" only applies to dimensions because dimension attribute changes are a tricky business.  Facts don't change.  New facts arise with different applicable dates.